# Distributing a GTK4 Windows application

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I have finished Bro codes 4 hour course on C and now I am interested in GUI applications using C. GTK looks good to me, but I don't understand anything on the GTK web site. After a few tutorials, I can build GTK code in Code::Blocks. Now I want to deploy and distribute it on Windows. Can anybody give me a guide?

I tried to do lot of things, such as the blog post in the GTK site-https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2014/08/01/how-to-build-your-gtk-application-on-windows/, but I don't know to do anything after creating a PKGBUILD file.

Comment: [so] is a site for focussed question on software development. Ab initio tutorials are not a good fit here.

Comment: sorry for asking this here. Its just there is no clear info on how to do this.

Comment: Locate a gtk project on github or sourceforge that builds for windows and examine how it is packaged.